# Change density of the body dynamically

Tags: java, android, physics, andengine

In my game, I want to change density of my body object when it collide with other objects. I found something like following to change density but further I could not able to find any hint for this. So someone please help.

```
Fixture fixture = goldenBoxArrayList.get(i)
                                        .getGoldenBoxBody()
                                        .getFixtureList().get(0);
                                fixture.setDensity(0.5f);
```

After setting fixture data I could not able to set it to the body.

EDIT : I want to change my object body density when physics world in simulation

Comment: What are you trying to do? Why do you need to change the density of an object?

Comment: How to ask questions the smart way: [ask the goal, not the step](http://catb.org/~esr/faqs/smart-questions.html#goal).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about AndEngine but in Box2D you can call the following functions:

```
fixture->SetDensity(5.0f); //this fixture is attached to body below
body->ResetMassData(); //must call this after changing density
```

AndEngine's physics is just a JNI wrapper around Box2D so it should support all or a subset of Box2D features.

Also check *7.4 Using a Body* of [Box2D manual](http://www.box2d.org/manual.html), its possible to override mass data calculated from fixtures on a body using:

```
void SetMassData(const b2MassData* data);
```

Comment: Yes that I want. Your consideration work perfectly.